# standard deviation symbol σ is not being added to PDF using iText

Tags: itext, symbols

I am using iText to generate PDFs and I have a symbol σ which does not get added to the PDF.

Is this because of font selection (using HELVETICA_BOLD)?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Use the font Symbol.

Comment: I've added an answer that proves that Paulo's advice is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The σ-symbol doesn't exist in Helvetica, so you need to use the Symbol font. This is demonstrated in the [StandardDeviation](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/StandardDeviation). See [standard_deviation.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/standard_deviation.pdf):

[image]

This is how it's done:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    document.add(new Paragraph("The standard deviation symbol doesn't exist in Helvetica."));
    Font symbol = new Font(FontFamily.SYMBOL);
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph("So we use the Symbol font: ");
    p.add(new Chunk("s", symbol));
    document.add(p);
    document.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didnt realize I had to use the 's' . Is there anyway I can make this bold ? Also, where can I find the mapping ? i.e. s maps to signma ..

Comment: `s` maps to `sigma` because they have the same character value. See [the Symbol encoding table](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Symbol_(typeface)). There is no **bold** version of font Symbol. This means that you either have to search for a Symbol font that supports bold, or that you have to mimic bold as explained in the following question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838812/custom-font-weight-in-itextsharp